# How to prompt request for Always geolocation permission

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation

Is it possible, using Cordova plugins, to request for Always geolocation permission in iOS? I only could request for "Allow when in use" and "Allow once".
This leads to issue where the user rarely applies for background geolocations. For my app this is crucial and 100% of the users will want it to be function on the background - how can I achieve such a thing using Cordova?

Comment: On iOS 13 even if you ask for always permission the user initially sees a request for when in use/once. After some time of your app using their location the user will be prompted to allow always permission. I recommend you view this years WWDC video on location services

Comment: Yes I have noticed and faced the same behaviour you described.. So how big apps like Waze are pass this issue?
What is WWDC?

Comment: Waze and other apps will experience the same behaviour on iOS 13. [WWDC what’s new in core location](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/)